# For each character $f$ of a finite abelian group $G$, $|f(a)|=1$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

> Let, $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$. So there are exactyly $n$ characters of the group $G$. For each character $f$ we have $|f(a)|=1$.Hence the reciprocal $\displaystyle \frac{1}{f(a)}$ is equal to the complex conjugate $\overline{f(a)}$. Thus the function $\bar f$ defined by $\bar{f}(a)=\overline{f(a)}$ is also a character of $G$. Moreover we have, $\displaystyle \bar f(a)=\frac{1}{f(a)}=f(a^{-1})$ ofr every $a\in G$.

My question is on the first line. How $|f(a)|=1$ for each character $f$ of $G$ ?

Comment: Number theory? Does that imply to you that a character is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\Bbb{C}^*$? The reason I ask is that in representation theory of groups characters are not always homomorphisms. For finite abelian groups the characters of irreducible representations OTOH are homomorphisms (because the irreducible reps are all 1-dimensional). Anyway. If we know that $f$ is a homomorphism, and $g\in G$ is of a finite order $d\mid n$, then $f(g)^d=f(g^d)=f(1)=1$ and...

Comment: @Jyrki: I think in the context of finite abelian groups a character is generally a homomorphism.

Comment: @carmichael561 Yeah, that must be the case in OP's context. For example, otherwise there wouldn't be exactly $n$ characters irrespective of whether $G$ is abelian or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is a character and $G$ has order $n$, we have
$$ 1=f(e)=f(a^n)=f(a)^n$$
where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.

Therefore $f(a)$ is an $n$th root of unity, so in particular $|f(a)|=1$.